# Try/except statement not catching ValueError when converting string to int in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, valueerror

I am trying to convert get input from the user as an integer only, and provide error checking to make sure the user's input is valid. When checking to see if the user has entered a string, the program is supposed to display an error if what the user enters is not an integer. However, no matter how I structure this try/except, it is not displaying the error message, and instead bouncing me back to the Visual Studio editor and throwing the exception "invalid literal for int() with base 10". I have searched and searched all over this site and others, and everybody else with this issue is able to get it working using this code, but for some reason for me it just is not working. Can someone please help me figure out what is going wrong, or if there is another way to check for integer input, please point me in that direction. Any assistance is appreciated, and I apologize if there is a similar question on this site already, but I was unable to find one pertaining to my specific case. I am using the Python 3.7 interpreter (although 3.8 is what I have installed, VS does not yet support it). Here is my code:

```
    try:
        a = int(input("Input: "))
    except ValueError:
        print(a)
```

Comment: You're not printing an error message, you're just printing whatever they entered.

Comment: But that won't work, because the variable isn't assigned if the conversion fails.

Comment: This is the correct way to validate input. Does it work if you run the script from a terminal window instead of VS?

Comment: What if a user enters a number, but it's not an integer? Would that be acceptable? In this case you should use @gelonida answer, but modify it so that ```a = int(float(inp))```.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried from the terminal and it worked. Thanks for the feedback! Looks like I'll be switching back to PyCharm, since Visual Studio is not really suited to Python development.

Comment: I think it's bet to use whatever environment you feel comfortable with. A lot of people I know are using Visual Studio Code and are very happy with it. I still think that this is a configuration issue and if you really wanted to use VS Code you could after having found out the issue. Please look at my answer, which I slightly modified and the comment, that I added. But in the end use whatever feels best for you. PyCharm is also a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you show is wrong.

If an exception occurs, then `a` will not have been assigned.
The code that was working for others was probably very similar but different.

Here an example with try except, that prompts the user until there is some valid input.
It also prints the path to the python executable and its version in order to be sure, that this is not a version issue. an IDE should not be able to ignore a try except statement.

I never heard of something like this and assume, that there is some other difference than pycharm vs Visual studio code.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable, sys.version_info)  # for debugging only
while True:
    inp = input("Input: ")
    try:
        a = int(inp)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid input", inp, ". You should enter a number. Please retry")

print("A is", a)
```

I don't know whether you want to force the user to enter correct data or whether you just want to detect an error. 
Just adapt it to your exact needs

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. To clarify, the code I provided was just an example I used for testing as to why the try/except wouldn't work. In my actual code I have the except portion printing a string, not the variable. I tried the exact code I provided (with a string instead of a being printed), as well as yours, and neither worked.  I just tried it from the terminal, and it worked perfectly! Evidently Visual Studio has issues with running Python (this is not the only issue I have encountered trying to run my code). I will likely switch back to PyCharm for Python programming. Thanks!

Comment: Please do **always** show the **exact** code, that you try and that is failing.

Please also be sure, that **exactly** the same code (with not one character modified) is working with Pycharm and failing with Visual Studio Code.

Even one different character can change the entire behavior.

I  suggest that you copy paste my code from my answer (with no modification) to try to reproduce the problem and only if you cannot reproduce the error you use the smallest piece of code you have, that works with one and fails with the other.

Comment: please note, I also slightly enhanced my answer.
An IDE should not have any impact on whether an exception is caught or not.